# Angular Material Theme import in Angular 2 not working in Webstorm

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I am trying to import the built in themes of angular material 2 but web-storm is unable to the resolve the file path and find directory although my theme file is residing in that exact directory. i have tried different methods to import but all resulted in same issue. Here is how i am importing in my **styles.scss** file

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

The IDE starts highlighting the path from **material** stating the problem.

This is the whole path of my theme file.

```
/media/rehan/New Volume/tic-tac-toe/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As i am working with a Angular CLI based project in angular 2 so i simply added the theme file to the **.angular-cli.json** file under the styles object using the following path which may vary depending on where the angular material has been installed:

```
 "styles": [ "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pi‌​nk.css"]
```

Comment: You also have to restart `ng serve` as changes to `.angular-cli.json` are not monitored for changes as far as I can tell.